Issues listing directory contents with dartssh2 package
I'm using thedartssh2: ^2.10.0 package in Flutter to connect to an SFTP server and list the contents of a directory. The connection is successful,  but I've encountered an issue where the server returns an SSH_Message_Request_Failure() message, which may indicate that the server failed to handle the request properly.
SSHClient? _sshClient; 

Future<void> _connectSFTP() async {
  try {
    final socket = await SSHSocket.connect(
      'example.com',
      22,
    );
    _sshClient = SSHClient(
      socket,
      username: 'your-username',
      onPasswordRequest: () => 'your-password',
      printDebug: print, // Enable detailed logging
      printTrace: print,
    );
    print('SSHClient connected to SFTP server.');
    await listRemoteDirectory();
  } catch (e) {
    if (e is SocketException) {
      print('Network error: $e'); 
    } else {
      print('Connection error: $e'); 
    }
  }
}

Future<void> listRemoteDirectory() async {
  try {
    final sftp = await _sshClient!.sftp();
    if (sftp == null) {
      return;
    }
    print('SFTP client created successfully.');

    const directoryPath = '/';

    // Add a timeout for the listdir operation
    final items = await sftp
        .listdir(directoryPath)
        .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 30));
    if (items.isEmpty) {
      print('The directory $directoryPath is empty.');
    } else {
      for (final item in items) {
        print('Item found: ${item.longname}');
      }
    }
  } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
    print('Timeout error occurred: $e');
  } on SftpStatusError catch (e) {
    print('SFTP status error: $e');
  } on SftpAbortError catch (e) {
    print('Operation aborted: $e');
  } on SftpExtensionUnsupportedError catch (e) {
    print('Unsupported extension: $e');
  } on SftpExtensionVersionMismatchError catch (e) {
    print('Extension version mismatch: $e');
  } catch (e) {
    print('An unexpected error occurred: $e');
  } finally {
    print('listRemoteDirectory method execution completed.');
  }
}

Output:
I/flutter ( 2968): SSHClient connected to SFTP server
I/flutter ( 2968): <- _SSHNativeSocket(default.sftp.server:22): 
I/flutter ( 2968): <- _SSHNativeSocket(default.sftp.server:22): SSH_Message_Channel_Confirmation(recipientChannel: 0, senderChannel: 0)
I/flutter ( 2968): -> _SSHNativeSocket(default.sftp.server:22): SSH_Message_Channel_Request(recipientChannel: 0, requestType: subsystem, wantReply: true, subsystemName: sensor)
...
I/flutter ( 2968): <- _SSHNativeSocket(default.sftp.server:22): SSH_Message_Request_Failure()
I/flutter ( 2968): -> _SSHNativeSocket(default.sftp.server:22): SSH_Message_Global_Request(requestName: keepalive@openssh.com, wantReply: true)
...
I/flutter ( 9787): SFTP client created successfully.
**I/flutter ( 2968): <- _SSHNativeSocket(default.sftp.server:22): SSH_Message_Request_Failure()**
...


Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Verified the SFTP path is correct by successfully listing it with a command-line SFTP client.
Confirmed the SFTP user has the necessary permissions for access.
Tested various directory paths with the dartssh2 package, but received no output or errors.
Added timeout and error handling to the code.
Enabled additional debug logging to trace the issue.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for any advice.

Not sure if you simplified the code above, but you have empty catch blocks. That's where you might see errors. Try a different SFTP server. Never had a problem connecting to a Linux server, but have had problems connecting to Synology with this package.

Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check the catch blocks for any errors. Have you used this package for listing remote directories, writing remote files, or file uploads? If so, any tips or issues you've encountered?

All of the above, and all generally successful except against one version of Synology. You might learn something from a wireshark (even though you'd see encrypted packets) - does the server respond or not to the last request? Also turn up debug on the client. (I'll edit the question to show how).

Thank you for your insights! I added the additional debug as you suggested and found some response issues. I’ll also check the server’s response with further debugging on the client.

That's the issue I see with certain servers. With working servers you see the client send an SftpInitPacket and receive an SftpVersionPacket. With non-working servers the version packet isn't received. I've never found out why and just avoid the non-working servers.
